# How do you handle an aggregate root with a collection of child entities whose update frequency is different than the root?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, aggregateroot

We have an aggregate root in our system and is has child entities in a collection. The problem is that the container needs to be updated very frequently, on a transaction basis, and the children entities don't, they in fact hardly ever change, they are more configuration like in nature.

My first reflex was to separate them into two different aggregate roots because our of application requirements. But I was reminded of the cascade delete rule, if we delete the one then the delete should cascade, so their lifetimes are linked.

We stumbled over this problem when we discovered that we have a caching problem. Changes to the children entities (configuration) were not being reflected in the system at runtime because the parent was unaware of the changes (we had them as one aggregate root but someone had created a repository for its children).

Comment: Why are the different update frequencies a problem? If the only problem you have stems from the fact that "someone" created a repo for the children, then your question belongs to programmers.SE - you have a people/process problem, not a technical one.

Comment: Because the transnational updates will be millions a day. The configuration data, the children entity updates will happen maybe once a month. We need the speed, and constantly overwriting rows with data that hasn't changed will kill the system. But this is a technical problem which resulted in a process problem, because people didn't know how to solve this problem correctly.

Comment: Don't the main aggregate need the configuration around to perform it's tasks? That would imply always having to load the configuration no?

Answer (score 6):

The main driver for aggregate boundaries are the invariants of your domain - or in other terms, aggregate boundaries should be consistency boundaries. **Things that must change together *atomically* must be in the same aggregate.**

The cascading delete is (with regards to aggregate boundaries) rather a nice-to-have than a rule. You can always enforce the fact that a `Parent` still lives by requiring one at the place where you load `Child` entities. With this design, you can make `Parent` and `Child` different aggregates, while still enforcing the rule that no "free floating" `Child` aggregates can be requested. And deleting `Child` aggregates in response to a deleted `Parent` is easy if you have domain events in place.

*Note: All this is under the assumption that your domain invariants allow separating the aggregates in the first place.*

Comment: Would you mind expanding on what would or wouldn't allow separating the aggregates.

Comment: That depends entirely on your domain rules, so you have to find that out together with your domain experts. It's typically a trade-off somewhere between "must change together" and "may be changed simultaneously by another user". [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31585706/219187) provides a little guidance and an example to find these rules.

Answer (score 4):

*This might be better in a discussion format, rather than a Q&A format.  I'd recommend trying the audience at [DomainDrivenDesign](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/domaindrivendesign/conversations/topics) or [DDDCQRS](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dddcqrs)*

Are you sure that you have a *business requirement* to delete data in your domain model?  That's really unusual -- in most domain models I've seen, an aggregate will reach an "end of life" state, (example: AccountClosed), but doesn't actually get removed from the system.

A common trap in aggregate design is to think about the structure of the entities.  "A has a B" does not necessarily mean that they are part of the same aggregate; the key idea is "A needs to keep B and C consistent".  You can think about it like a graph; state B and state C are nodes in the graph, the consistency rules are the edges.  If you can't traverse the graph from B to C, then they don't need to be part of the same aggregate, and probably shouldn't be.

My instinct is that caching should be the right answer here.  If you are processing millions of transactions per day, and the collection only changes once per month, then simply using a cached value of the collection should produce the right answer most of the time.

In this, I'm influenced by Udi Dahan's essay [Race Conditions Don't Exist](http://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/); by coupling this configuration collection with the rest of the aggregate, you are essentially asserting that changes to the configuration (which are rare) are understood by the business to be happening precisely between two other changes to the aggregate.  3M transactions per day averages 1 per 30ms; are you really scheduling your configuration changes that precisely?

The usual pattern here would be that the consistency rule is removed from the domain model; instead, you monitor for changes that introduce an inconsistency, and mitigate them.  That depends upon there being a reasonable way to detect the errors, an efficient way to mitigate them, and a mechanic for keeping the rate under control.

The latter of these would normally be done by having the clients/the application check their local copy of the collection, and making sure the command sent is consistent with that before dispatching the command to the domain model.  (Possible questions for your domain experts: how quickly do the configuration changes need to be applied?  Do the configuration changes happen when the aggregate is changing frequently or when it is quiet?)

Another possibility might be to change your persistence strategy; if the collection doesn't change often, then there are not a lot of change events related to it.  So maybe instead of persisting the aggregate, you look into persisting its history - in other words, using event-sourcing here.  Maybe if this aggregate lived in a micro service, you could limit the risk of the change?  Hard to say, at a million transactions per day, this aggregate sounds pretty important.

Comment: Did your applications never have privacy requirements? They are a pretty good reason to actually delete data instead of just hiding it.