# Is there a elegant way of putting domain validations inside domain layer?

Tags: validation, domain-driven-design, domain-model, rich-domain-model

I am new to domain driven design and there is one thing that is bothering me when I'm writing domain model. How to handle domain validation?

I am designing library management system where user can search through books and see if book is on the stock.
If it is not, user can create request for book so some kind of queue is created. Rule is that we don't have any book in stock. Right now I have information about quantity inside book entity and that is not a problem but what if i have different bounded context for requesting books and book catalog. Then I must somehow contact another vertical/service and ask (validate) that book quantity is zero before creating book aggregate.

Also I am checking if user have valid membership card, is book already borrowed by him, do user have active requests for any book.

**Things that bother me.**

I need to know what exactly to include in aggregate before passing it to domain model because of validations. I am not sure that is safest approach because my validations accuracy will depend from specification/query, etc.

Another very important thing. When application layer method start with execution and something is not valid client will get only validation messages for code that was executed and there is good chance there is more things that are preventing code for execution. This can be really inconvenient if user is filling some form.

**First thoughts for solving this problem.**

I have command/handler architecture and I am using MediatR so I am thinking to move domain validations between command and handler and that will solve my problems for now but that approach will spread domain knowledge across bounded context and domain model will not be smart enough to guard from not valid actions. More precise I will need to think before executing application method (handler) what I need to validate.

So I am really curious. Is there any clear way of handling domain validations inside domain model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any clear way of handling domain validations inside domain model?

Yes; they require work and careful thinking.

One aspect of careful thinking is to distinguish *message* validation from *domain logic*.  Message validation is an isolated thing, a message is valid or not according to the schema of the message -- are all of the required fields present, is the data in the right form, are the numbers in the allowed range, and so on.  Really, we're asking the question "did the client fill out the form correctly?"

Integrating a valid message with previously known information (aka, the "state" of the domain model) is a domain logic concern.  State is chosen deliberately - the domain model *is* a state machine for the bookkeeping of your domain.

Depending on your domain, and the information that is available, there can be states that mean that the client doesn't get what they want.  "The road less traveled" doesn't mean that things are *invalid*.

Furthermore, if your system is distributed (different pieces of data are the responsibility of different authorities), then any locally cached copies of that data are necessarily stale, and may be out of date.  See Pat Helland's [Memories, Guesses, and Apologies](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pathelland/2007/05/15/memories-guesses-and-apologies/).  That we will sometimes produce an incorrect answer is an inevitable consequence of distributing the work.  If we're responsible, then we performed a cost benefit analysis to ensure that the expected benefits of distributing the work offset the expected risks.

Comment: I understand that message validation is separate thing from domain validation but I am confused about domain validation. 
If we want to perform validation inside domain should than aggregate read all child entities that are needed for domain action and validation.

Should domain layer have access to database so validations will read data and validate it independently so we does not have to pass aggregate and think about what is need for validation?

One important thing to say, I am now reading aggregate in my application layer, maybe this is wrong?

Comment: I read your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662541/ddd-do-i-really-need-to-load-all-objects-in-an-aggregate-performance-concerns/37663737#37663737) that full aggregate should be read because of behavior not the structure and I understand what you are saying about states. 

Thank you for your time and answer, much appreciated.